# Using Ionic Capcitor geolocation plugin, Iphone its taking around 45sec to 1.5 mins to fetch current location

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using capcitor geolocation plugin to find current location coordinates(latitude and longitude).

```
const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({enableHighAccuracy:true});
const center = {lat: coordinates.coords.latitude, lng: coordinates.coords.longitude};
```

But in Iphone its taking around 45sec to 1.5 mins to fetch current location.

I have alao used below code. But this is sometime fast sometime slow.

```
 const id = await Geolocation.watchPosition({}, (coordinates, err) => {
                        Geolocation.clearWatch({id});
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                        console.log('getCenter ios',coordinates);
                        const center = {lat: coordinates.coords.latitude, lng: coordinates.coords.longitude}; 
                    });
```

Is there any other implementation or free/paid plugin available, which can fetch current location coordinates faster on iphone.

Comment: use `enableHighAccuracy:false` if you want fastest results, but they will be less accurate

Comment: @jcesarmobile tried enableHighAccuracy:false but still its slow